# Read text from a T-Shirt image

Tags: image, ocr

I am trying to read text from a t-Shirt image. 
I tried tesserect but i dont get the proper text.
There seems to be lots of ways to read from a white/constant background.. but not from any random scene..
What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this task you are facing same challenges as any other OCR project dealing with unconventional media (not paper scans) - variable colors, text on backgrounds, distortions in print surface, various angles, fonts, etc.  Each potential aspect that affects OCR quality requires a separate methodology and process how to handle it, and when they all work together, good results can be achieved.

This Blog posting I wrote some time ago is a good place to start.  It addresses nearly every issue you may face in your task.

http://www.ocr-it.com/user-scenario-process-digital-camera-pictures-and-ocr-to-extract-specific-numbers

Take a look at other articles in the same Blog.

Sample image would definitely help to answer with more specifics.